# NFS mounts not working in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, mount, nfs

Before I upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 from 14, I used to be able to mount and access folders on WDMyCloud drives. Now I get the following error:

```
ls: Cannot open directory '/home/nas/Public': Operation not permitted.
```

I did not change anything on WDMyCloud. 
`showmount -e 192.168.0.19` produces:

```
/nfs *
```

exports entry on the server:

```
/nfs *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,insecure,crossmnt)
```

user with uid=1000 and gid=1000 on server can access all files. My uid on client is also 1000: `id balaji` produces this:

```
uid=1000(balaji) gid=1000(balaji) groups=1000(balaji),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd),113(sambashare),119(lpadmin)
```

fstab entry on client (it is a single line)

```
192.168.0.19:/nfs /home/nas nfs rw,udp,vers=3,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 0 0
```

`ls /home/nas` produces

```
Public

ls /home/nas/Public
ls: cannot access '/home/nas/Public/': Operation not permitted
```

I started having this problem after upgrading to ubuntu 16.04. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is `/nfs/Public` a separate filesystem on the server side (as suggested by the `crossmnt` option)? Are you explicitly exporting it?

Comment: Thanks, that fixes it. Looks like something changed on WdMyCloud recently and my upgrade had nothing to do with it breaking.

Answer (score 1):

Each NFS share must be explicitly exported in `/etc/exports`.

Can also try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nfs-common nfs-utils` just in case.

In `/etc/fstab`, `rw,udp,vers=3,soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192` can be replaced with just `auto` - over-specifying could sometimes cause some odd issues.